# Consuming values from 2 columns

Tags: sql-server

I am trying to figure out how to make a sort of "consumption" query where an INT value column (X) is subtracted from another INT column (Y) until it reaches 0, then stop.  The column DesiredResult and DesiredResultExplanation are here only for reference to the math being performed. This takes place in DESC date order (future consuming back to the present)

My initial approach was to use window functionality, but the problem is once the value (Y) reaches 0, it needs to stop performing a running total. Had similar issues using a CTE as well.

If changing the table structure will help at all, this can be done.

Version: SQL Server 2014 or higher

Thanks!

```
DECLARE @test TABLE
(
ID INT IDENTITY (1,1)
,PeriodDate DATE
,X INT
,Y INT
,DesiredResult INT
,DesiredResultExplanation VARCHAR(100)
)

INSERT INTO @test VALUES ('2017-05-01', 100,0, 100,'Nothing left to subtract.  Value is unchanged')
INSERT INTO @test VALUES ('2017-05-08', 200,0, 200,'Nothing left to subtract.  Value is unchanged')
INSERT INTO @test VALUES ('2017-05-15', 300,0, 100,'300 - 200 = 100  (Orig -1100 has been consumed)')
INSERT INTO @test VALUES ('2017-05-22', 400,0,-200,'400 - 600 = -200 ')
INSERT INTO @test VALUES ('2017-05-29', 500,-1100,-600, '500 - 1100 = -600')

SELECT *
FROM @test
ORDER BY PeriodDate DESC
```

Comment: Not sure what is `Nothing left to substract` and suddenly you substract. Because in your example colum `Y` doesnt change

Comment: Look at the column PeriodDate in DESC order.  the 1100 is consumed at 5/29 and moves backwards.  By the time it reaches 5/8 and 5/1 the 1100 was consumed.  Hope that makes sense

Comment: where the 1100 come from ?

Comment: Ohh is backwards?

Comment: It is a static value (an order being subtracted from a forecast).  In this example i just put down 1100.

Comment: Can you post what you have tried, as well as desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[DEMO](http://rextester.com/ZAYKV29954)**

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT *,
           SUM(X) OVER (ORDER BY PeriodDate DESC) accumulated   
    FROM @test
), parameter as (
    SELECT 1100 as startY
)    
SELECT *,
       CASE WHEN accumulated <= startY 
            THEN accumulated - startY
            WHEN LAG(accumulated) OVER (ORDER BY PeriodDate DESC) < startY
            THEN accumulated - startY
            ELSE X
       END as newDesire
FROM cte
CROSS JOIN parameter
ORDER BY PeriodDate DESC;
```

**OUTPUT**

[image]

**EDIT:** You can change the `LAG` condition with

```
 WHEN accumulated - X < startY
```

Comment: I forgot about using LAG!  This is the groundwork I needed.  Thanks Juan!

Comment: well if you see the key was use comulative `SUM` on the edit I choose to remove the `LAG` and think is easy to read